# Mapbox Static image with auto and pitch

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying to create a static image using the "auto" feature to correctly calibrate the image according to the polyline I pass to it. It works very well but I'd like to add a pitch in addition. 
I've tried something like this but I got this error: "Invalid query param pitch"

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/pin-s-a+9ed4bd(-122.46589,37.77343),pin-s-b+000(-122.42816,37.75965),path-5+f44-0.5(%7DrpeFxbnjVsFwdAvr@cHgFor@jEmAlFmEMwM_FuItCkOi@wc@bg@wBSgM)/auto/500x300?access_token=xxxxx**&pitch=50**

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

The `auto` parameter automatically sets the values for longitude, latitude, zoom, bearing, and pitch based on the overlay. When using `auto` you cannot set these values individually as the parameter replaces all of their values with the best settings for the overlay. From the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-a-static-map-from-a-style):

> If `auto` is added, the viewport will fit the bounds of the overlay. If
>   used, auto replaces lon, lat, zoom, bearing, and pitch.

If you'd like to set the pitch, you will need to supply your own values for longitude, latitude, zoom, and bearing as well. For example: https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/pin-s-a+9ed4bd(-122.46589,37.77343),pin-s-b+000(-122.42816,37.75965),path-5+f44-0.5(%7DrpeFxbnjVsFwdAvr@cHgFor@jEmAlFmEMwM_FuItCkOi@wc@bg@wBSgM)/-122.46589,37.75965,11,0,50/500x300?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}

Will return:

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand your answer ! So I need a way to find the coordinates of the center of the polyline and the zoom. Is there a function allowing me to find these values with MapBox API?

Comment: @Lecraver there is not a direct way to do this using any of Mapbox's APIs. However, you could use the start and end points of your polyline. You would still need to pass a separate zoom level though.

Comment: Too bad that's not possible! If my start and end point of the polyline are the same and it forms a circle, it's complicated to automate the zoom. There is also a risk that we don't see all the polyline

Comment: Hi Patrick, I'm sorry to insist but I can't find a solution to my problem...I could see that there is a function on the JavaScript part to zoom on the map and center automatically (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/). Impossible to have this feature in the SDK? Or to be able to override the "auto" parameter with additional parameters ? Thanks